# How to prevent other clients from using my Twilio turn servers

Tags: php, ios, cordova, security, twilio

I am using Twilio for my turn servers and it looks like you generate it with the server side language of your choice (PHP in my case) and then just print out the key. This will be used on a a mobile iOS/Android application.

My question, is since I'm obviously just making an Ajax call to my server, what's to stop anyone from just accessing that page and using my turn servers on their clients?

Comment: Are your AJAX calls not authenticated?

Comment: As in passing a synchronizer token on each call you mean? Yes, but then anyone can then generate the JWT, and copy my client side code to my servers.

Comment: Your signed token is generated on the client side? That doesn't sound secure.

Comment: No, generated server side, but stored client side (i.e. NSUserDefaults, LocalStorage, cookies, keychain, etc.)

Comment: Well, then only authenticated users can get one and access your API. If a user abuses it, ban them. If you want to make it harder to reverse engineer, use common techniques like certificate pinning and obfuscation. But those only slow things down and not stop it completely.

Comment: True ya, it's a difficult problem to solve. I'm sure there's no 100% foolproof way to prevent it, but the more you do the better. Obviously if it slows things down it may not be the best choice. But using all security measures that don't should be a no-brainer.

Comment: Well the docs say this: Security is very important to us and we have made sure that you as the developer are in control. You decide what access rights to grant a Twilio Client device using capability tokens generated with one of our helper libraries. We ensure that any tampering with the token parameters is detected and the appropriate actions are taken.